# how to break line in list in python email

Tags: python, html, email, flask, gmail

I am trying to query a list from my Flask database and then send it out as a html email. However, i am unable to break them into different lines.

for example, instead of:

a

b

c

i get abc currently in the email. i've tried adding "\n" in the loop but it doesnt seem to work. does anyone know how i can break it into different rows?

```
def mail():
  sender_email = "xx@gmail.com"
  message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
  message["Subject"] = "xx"
  message["From"] = sender_email
  message["To"] = user_mail
  add = '\n'
  
  list = Lines.query.all()
  for s in list:
    add += str(s.title) + '\r\n'

  print(add)

  # Write the plain text part
  text = "Thank you for submitting a xx! Here are the lines submitted: " + add

# write the HTML part
  html = """\
    <html>
    <head><head style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <table role="presentation" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border:20;border-spacing:20;background:#cc0000;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="padding:20;color:#ffffff;">
                Your xxxxx was submitted!
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</head>
    
        <p>Thank you for submitting a xx! Here are the lines submitted for your reference:<br><br>
        """ + add + """
            <br></br>
        </p>

    </html>
    """
    # convert both parts to MIMEText objects and add them to the MIMEMultipart message
  part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
  part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")
  message.attach(part1)
  message.attach(part2)
... 

  server.sendmail("xx@gmail.com", user_mail, message.as_string())
  return redirect(url_for('complete'))
```

Comment: use this `"\n".join(list)`

Comment: thanks for this! i tried using it but maybe to clarify, i was only going to extract one column ('title') of the entire list table (hence i used `for s in list: str(s.title))`. but when i used `"\n".join(s.title)`, what happened was that only the last value of the table was printed. :/

Comment: `\n` won't work as it's not proper html syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
list = Lines.query.all()
for s in list:
    add += str(s.title) + '<br>'
```

or (using format vs string concatenation):

```
list = Lines.query.all()
for s in list:
    add += '{}<br>'.format(str(s.title))
```

or (python 3.6+ f strings):

```
list = Lines.query.all()
for s in list:
     add += f"{s.title}<br>"
```

`\n` is not for HTML, but `<br>` is.

Comment: This worked like a charm!!! Thank you so much!!!!! i've been trying it out the whole day - thank you thank you and thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an empty string and keep adding in the loop.

```
str = ""
for s in list:
     str += f"{s.title}\n"
```

Comment: thank you! i tried this and printed it in terminal, and yes it appeared in separated lines in the terminal! however it is still in a whole chunk of text without line breaks in the email. i am wondering if it is because emails are auto-formatted or something? :/